# Accessing a variable that is part of the parent method

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C and I am unsure how to access a variable across methods. For instance:

```
void merge_sort(int * a, int n) {
    int *aux = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    sort(a, n);
    free(aux);
}
```

When I try to execute this, the compiler tells me that `aux` cannot be accessed in `sort`. So how can I fix this? Do I make `aux` a global variable? Or do I use something such as `extern`?

Here is the rest of my code right now :

```
    void sort(long int *a, long int *aux, int low, int high) {
        int size = high - low;
        if (size <= INSERTION_THRESHOLD) {
                insertion_sort(a + low, size);
        }
        else {
                if (high <= low) {
                        return;
                }
                int mid  = low + (high - low)/2;
                sort(a, aux, low, mid);
                sort(a, aux, mid + 1, high);
                merge(a, aux, low , mid, high);
        }
}

void merge(long int *a, long int *aux,  int low, int mid, int high) {

        int i = low;
        int j = mid + 1;

        for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
                *(aux + k) = *(a + k);
        }

        for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
                if (i > mid) {
                        *(a + k) = *(aux + (j++));
                }
                else if (j > high) {
                        *(a + k) = *(aux + (i++));
                }
                else if (aux[j] < aux[i]) {
                        *(a + k) = *(aux + (j++));
                }
                else {
                        *(a + k) = *(aux + (i++));
                }
        }
```

Comment: aux is a local variable to the merge_sort function . If you want to access aux in sort() then try sending it as a parameter to the sort()

Comment: Don't use global variables except under duress.  Assume they're the wrong answer.  Occasionally, just occasionally, they're the right answer (think of `stdout`, for example), but most often they are the wrong answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `aux` variable? How do you expect to use it in the `sort()` function? Can you declare it as a local variable in `sort()` instead?

Comment: Its an temporary array that I can copy elements to while merging in merge sort.

Comment: Hi I updated to include the code so you guys can get the context.